# ProgressBar for multiple WebBrowser instances

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I aggregate the [CurrentProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) properties of multiple (dynamic amount) of WebBrowsers together so that a ProgressBar will look accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (currentProgressBar != null)
        {
            (currentProgressBar as ToolStripProgressBar).Maximum = (currentProgressBar as ToolStripProgressBar).Maximum;
            (currentProgressBar as ToolStripProgressBar).Value = preValue + ((100 * (Int32)e.CurrentProgress) / (Int32)e.MaximumProgress);
            if (e.CurrentProgress >= e.MaximumProgress)
            {
                preValue = (currentProgressBar as ToolStripProgressBar).Value;
            }
        }
```

This was how i was able to get the progress bar to display correctly for multiple web browser controls.